# Should I add a method/constructor argument for an object that can be queried from another argument

Tags: java

Assuming that I have this:

```
public class A {
   private B b;

   public B getB() {
     return b;
   }
}
```

Now, I have a class that needs A and B.  The questions is, should the constructor be accepting only A, and I would then query B from A, or should the constructor be asking for both A **and** B?

Should it be this:

```
public MyClass(A a) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = a.getB();
}
```

or this:

```
public MyClass(A a, B b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}
```

p/s: I think this is a rather noobish questions, but whatever.

p/p/s: Thinks this should have been a community wiki?  I don't have enough permission though. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's an excellent question! as there's a "contradiction" of good practices.

The first solution applies the rule: "try to pass the least number of parameters to a method (or constructor)" (Robert C martin mentions this rule in his book Clean Code)

The second snippet follows the rule of [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), which says That MyClass should know as little as possible about A.

Personally I would go with the second option, but in some scenarios I might go for the first one.

Comment: You totally nailed my dilemma with the Law of Demeter.  I also don't want my constructor to 'lie' (saying I need A, when I ALSO need B)...

Answer (score 1):

the second options allows a user to call MyClass with a non related B:

```
new MyClass(new A(),new B());
```

while the first option ensures MyClass uses the same B...

so it is up to your need which is prefered.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where classes A and B might be subclassed, it may be very important in MyClass to always be using the B subclass that corresponds to the particular A subclass in use. Similar considerations apply even without subclassing if the B instance needs to be correctly configured for a particular A instance. Adding a `getB()` method to the definition of class A is part of several design patterns that help with this kind of requirement. In those cases, the MyClass constructor should take only an instance of A and retrieve the correct B instance from A.

In cases where MyClass can work with a range of B instances for any particular A instance, then a two-parameter constructor makes more sense. This moves the responsibility of generating a B instance to be used with any particular A instance to whatever client classes are creating instances of MyClass. That might be exactly the right solution for various mix-and-match types of structures. But this all begs the question: Why does class A have a `getB()` method in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you have something like the following it would make sence to let let `Car` only take an `Engine` as constructor argument since it makes sence to say `engine.getEngineParts()`.

```
class Car
class Engine
class EnginePart
```

If the contract is weaker I would advice using setter injection and using a default constructor.

If you create a constructor as follows you cannot be sure the `EnginePart` actually belongs to the `Engine`. This might be desirable on occasions though, e.g., when you want to *add* an `EnginePart` to an `Engine`, e.g.,

```
EngineAssembler (Engine engine, EnginePart part) {
    engine.addPart(part);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the problem.
it depends on what A and B are.

anyway, i choose the constructor with A as parameter (even if your question is too generic)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is when you are making the Object A, set the value of B through setter or constructor and pass the A object to new class.

```
public class MyClass{
  A a;
  Myclass(A a){
  this.a = a;
}

public void doSomething()
{
System.out.println(a.getB());
}
}
```

MyClass can always work with only one instance variable. Because you can always get B with a.getB(). If B can't be null, make sure you checks the nullness of the B, when it is operating on it.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to not pass B at all, but instead, to have MyClass talk to A whenever it needs B to do something?